# Is it possible left and right bash trimming with the # and % operators in one command?

Tags: bash, filepath, trim

Is it possible to rewrite this piece of code

```
$ x="/foo/somefile.txt"
$ y=${x%.*}
$ echo ${y##*/}
somefile
```

without the variable y?

I mean like a one command with left and right trimming at one time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible left and right bash trimming with the # and % operators in one command?

No, it's not possible in bash.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain expansions, but in this particular case, you can still achieve what you intended with a single expansion :

```
/$ x="/foo/somefile.txt"
/$ shopt -s extglob
/$ echo ${x//@(*\/|.*)/}
somefile
```

So it will replace two patterns with empty string : `*\/` and `.*`

Comment: Note that this will turn `/foo/somefile.txt.gz` into just `somefile`, while the two-step modification in the question will turn it into `somefile.txt`.